# Could not build my project in Android Studio Preview 3.2-beta 1

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio throws the below error if I try to build my app. How can I solve this error? Any help would be appreciated.

```
NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ManipalClientApp_NoLogoNew'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta01.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta01.
         > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0-beta01/gradle-3.2.0-beta01.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0-beta01/gradle-3.2.0-beta01.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authorization Required
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta01.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0-beta01/gradle-3.2.0-beta01.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0-beta01/gradle-3.2.0-beta01.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authorization Required

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 0s
Could not HEAD 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0-beta01/gradle-3.2.0-beta01.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authorization Required
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

Answer (score 0):

try to install the latest version of gradle and sync it with your project and restart android studio.